# How to add mouse-tracking effect to specific wordpress row?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to add a **mouse-tracking effect** to my wordpress website. I did it, but I don't know how to add the effect to a specific row.

A short introduction, I know something about the CSS language, but a bit or nothing about HTML and JS. This is what I've done:

Once created the mouse-tracking effect, I've tried to add it to a specific row   using CSS (adding to the class `ball` static and absolute positions), but it doesn't work. So I create a new `row ID` (#container), 
assuming to apply the class `ball` to the new row ID, but I don't understand how to do it.

**HTML:**

```
<h1>Giovanni</h1>`
    <div class="ball">
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  document.addEventListener("mousemove",function (event) {
      const mouseX = event.pageX
      const mouseY = event.pageY

      const ball = document.querySelector("div.ball")

      ball.style.left = mouseX + "px"
      ball.style.top = mouseY + "px"
  })
</script>
```

Mouse-tracking effect works ok, but all-over the page.

Answer (score 0):

It works on the entire page because you are binding it to the entire document with `document.`.

You need to target the right element in the dom, in this case using: `document.getElementByClassName("ball");` because you are targeting for certain class name, if you wanted to use an ID you would use `document.getElementById("ball");`

Where `document.` returns the entire page, these two functions returns OF the entire document the elements with the especified classes or id's.

```
<h1>Giovanni</h1>`
<div class="ball"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var el = document.getElementByClassName("ball"); //select the div with ball class
el.addEventListener("mousemove",function (event) {
const mouseX = event.pageX
const mouseY = event.pageY

const ball = document.querySelector("div.ball")

ball.style.left = mouseX + "px"
ball.style.top = mouseY + "px"
})

</script>
```